# Org mode to latex exports themes or templates

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, exporting

Where can i find some good org to latex export templates, for example, i found some good ones for HTML exports see fniessen excellent work [here](https://github.com/fniessen/org-html-themes)

is there any similar projects for org-to-latex export?